# How is the content of this webpage protected?

Tags: html

I have a little homework webpage, so I am often looking for ideas. I went to Liz's ielts [page](https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-multiple-choice-listening-turtles/).

Normally, a right click and you can look at the source code, but Liz is smart: if you right click you just get a "Alert content is protected" message.

Very interesting! I've never seen that before. How is that done?

Comment: Just don't do this. It also prevents your users to use the site as expected. For example I can't select any text on mobile, for example to translate it, or copy a piece of text to share with a friend. Things that users do. Also, it don't prevent smart persons to copy the content, because you can always go to inspector and copy the HTML.

Comment: if you try to 
Press  F12  to inspect the webpage @pedroski

Answer (score 1):

As the page's source shows, this is done with Javascript that overrides the context menu event with a function that does nothing:

```
<script id="wpcp_disable_Right_Click" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.ondragstart = function() { return false;}
/* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Disable context menu on images by GreenLava Version 1.0
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
    function nocontext(e) {
       return false;
    }
    document.oncontextmenu = nocontext;
//]]>
</script>
```

There are other javascript functions in there that help protect the content too, such as one that prevents selection by overriding the mouse down event.